# Speedbit has hijacked my Firefox home page

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

How can I get rid of the Speedbit address that has been set as my Firefox home page? I am unable to change my home page to Yahoo, Google, etc. through usual methods. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17):

I do not have experience with SPEEDbit, but in general, to restore Firefox's home page settings:

1. Go to `about:config`
2. **Reset** (`Right-click -> Reset`) the following preferences:

   - `startup.homepage_override_url`
   - `browser.startup.page`
   - `browser.startup.homepage`

   [image: reset]

I suspect that you could also do a search (filter) for `speedbit` in `about:config` and **reset** any related preferences. This would hopefully restore other hijacked preferences!

---

### Update:

***Warning: the following was performed by a professional in a secure, virtual test environment. Do not try this at home.***

To provide a more complete answer, I went ahead and installed the SPEEDbit `Download Accelerator Plus` (DAP) and their *"recommended"* additions or settings: `Search Predict`, `Video Downloader`, and `Video Accelerator`.

[image: desktop]

[image: add-ons]

**Note:** You can **disable** these add-ons by going to `about:addons`.

---

Now, this is what my new Firefox profile looks like:

[image: firefox profile]

As you can see, SPEEDbit added a toolbar, changed my home page and search bar.

---

Let's try to reset the home page using the GUI (`Options > General > Startup`):

[image: reset home page]

**Note:** if you cannot restore the home page using the GUI, you can do so by **resetting** the following preferences in `about:config`:

- `pref.browser.homepage.disable_button.restore_default`
- `browser.startup.homepage`

It seems to have worked...

[image: about:home]

However, `Download Accelerator Plus` and `Video Accelerator` are still running:

[image: tray]

So, let's restart the computer to see if our change persists.

**SUCESS!** *(I would post a screenshot, but it would be identical to the one above. You'll have to trust me.)*

---

Your question only covered the **home page**, but I want us to poke around `about:config` to see what else SPEEDbit has got its dirty little paws into.

[image: about:config]

So, to restore any other hijacked preferences, **reset** the following:

- `browser.search.defaultenginename`
- `browser.search.defaulturl`
- `browser.search.order.1`
- `browser.search.selectedEngine`
- `browser.startup.homepage_override_url`
- `keyword.URL`

Your profile should now look like this:

[image: restored]

---

And finally, if you want to hide the Video Downloader toolbar, **uncheck**:

```
View > Toolbars > SpeedBit Video Downloader
```

[image: toolbar]

---

## NOT SO FAST!

So, after one last reboot with `Download Accelerator Plus` and `Video Accelerator` still running, the search bar and `keyword.URL` were hijacked again. Is it one of the **add-ons**? Is is the aforementioned programs? Time to investigate. I'll skip the details and simply post my findings... `>:(`

- **Disabling** all three add-ons was unsuccessful. The preferences were hijacked again after a reboot.
- **Unchecking** `Mozilla/Firefox` integration under Download Accelerator Plus's `Options > Advanced` was unsuccessful.

  [image: browser integration]
- Disabling Download Accelerator Plus or Video Accelerator from **auto-starting** was unsuccessful.
- Disabling the Video Accelerator **service** from auto-starting was unsuccessful.

The *only thing* that stopped Firefox's preferences from being hijacked was to **uninstall** Download Accelerator Plus. Once you've uninstalled the software, retracing the above steps should work properly.

---

### Conclusion:

If you want my personal opinion on the software, I would advise you not to use it. Due to it's rogue nature and malware-like appearance (ads, ads, and more ads), I have a hard time believing "265 million users" were satisfied with the product.

Comment: Great answer @iglvzx, perhaps you should consider writing about it for the SU blog?

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed toolbar or other software from speedbit and that is the reason you can't reset your home page.

Check if you have any software or toolbars from speedbit installed. if you have, check in its settings to see if it is resetting your home page.

If you don't have any such software then it could be problem with browser. try the steps @iglvzx has specified.